# jQuery - Grab all next() up to a certain quantity

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablerow

Ok, basically, I have an element that I get which happens to be a `<tr>` element.

But If I find a `<td>` element with a rowspan that is greater than 1, within any of the `<tr>` elements, I need to exclude these `<tr>` elements, starting with the $("td").parent() of where the rowspan > 1, and I need to exclude all other `<tr>` elements up to the rowspan quantity within an `each()`

So something like this:

```
$("td").each(function{
if ($(this).attr('rowspan') > 1)
    var curRowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
    // So now rowspan can equal 2, 3, 4, 5, and higher.
    // Now I need to exclude the NEXT <tr> elements based on the quantity of rowspans.
    // So if the rowspan = 2, than I need to exclude $(this).parent() and $(this).parent().next() which seems easy enough, but I need this to work on more than 2 rowspans also.  Needs to exclude the current <tr> element and all <tr> elements after, until it reaches the rowspan quantity indicated by curRowspan.
    // HOW TO DO THIS and return false out of the each() for each of these `<td>` elements within that quantity of `<tr>` elements indicated by the rowspan of a `<td>` element???
});
```

Comment: What if you have two `<tr>` in a row that contain a `<td>` with a rowspan?

Comment: Than it will need to grab the rowspan with the bigger value.  That is the rowspan that affects more `<tr>` elements.  For example, if I found a rowspan=4 on the 1st `<tr>` element, and a rowspan=2 on the 2nd `<tr>` element, since the 4 affects up to the 4th `<tr>` element, than this is more than the rowspan=2 on the 2nd `<tr>` element because this would only affect up to the 3rd `<tr>` element.  So it should always grab the rowspan quantity that affects the most `<tr>` elements until it reaches the end of the `<tr>` elements that it affects and exclude those `<tr>` elements returning false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to indicate you are ignoring that row. I feel as though there is a better way to optimize this selector though. [Slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) looks promising.

http://jsfiddle.net/UG35Q/2/

```
$("td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('rowspan') > 1) {        
        var curRowspan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
        $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, curRowspan).addClass('markRow');
    }
});
```

Comment: But the `<tr>` elements already have a class defined on them.  So how will I check for the class when I need to exclude it?  `hasClass()` I'm assuming?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - I didn't really know what you meant by exclude in your question. Do you want to remove the row from the DOM? What are you doing with the row that contains the td? Does that also get excluded?

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - I updated my answer. I had copy/pasted your original code and there were a couple syntax errors that I fixed up. If you just want to remove the row then use `remove()` instead of `addClass`.

Comment: No, don't want to remove the row, I just want to exclude it, like return false within the each().  I think I can use what you have here though, which is great.  Testing now... and thanks :)  Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of all rows that have a td for every column? If so, then you could do $('tr').filter( function() { if $(this).children().length == column count) return true;});